# Could activity be set as live wallpaper?

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

Is it possible to my current activity as a background or a wallpaper of device?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible on Android. All live wallpapers on Android ***must*** extend `WallpaperService`. There is a great tutorial on making live wallpapers [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLiveWallpaper/article.html).

Comment: can  I use my xml layouts in WallpaperService .

Comment: @URAndroid that depends on what your layouts do. Go through the tutorial I linked to, and see if you can use your existing code somehow.

Comment: how Can i set livewallpaper from click event of Activity. or how can i bind livewallpaper with Activity.